# How do I use an npmjs Automation Token?

Tags: npm

As described here https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-02-npm-automation-tokens/, Automation Tokens are useful in CI/CD to bypass 2FA during `npm publish`.

I found it easy to create one; however, I can't find any tutorials on how to actually use the token. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer by searching the Internet for `npm auth token`.

Put inside `~/.npmrc`

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=your_auth_token
```

I couldn't figure out how to get this to work with `yarn npm publish`, so I'm sticking to `npm publish`.